# why is it bad to declare functions in code blocks i.e if..else statements

Tags: javascript

taken from YDKJS.

```
foo(); // "b"

var a = true;

if (a) {
    function foo() { console.log( "a" ); }
} else {
    function foo() { console.log( "b" ); }
}
```

Comment: This might give you a good reason -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements

Comment: Better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768233/6586663